# How do I give text a shadow in python-pptx?

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I am working on a project where I have to create a PowerPoint using python-pptx. I need to add text that has a shadow, to appear like this:

[image]

How do I format text with a shadow in python-pptx?

Here is the code I'm using :

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches, Pt
from pptx.enum.shapes import MSO_SHAPE
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor
from pptx.enum.dml import MSO_THEME_COLOR
Temppath ="C:/Rept/Template/Template16.pptx"
prs= Presentation(Temppath)
slides =prs.slides[12]
shapes=slides.shapes
Month= "October"
premont="Septmeber"

for shape in shapes:
    if shape.has_text_frame:
       Text_frame=shape.text_frame
       text=Text_frame.text
       text= text.split(" ")
       if "PrevMonth" in text:
            strText=" ".join(text)
            strText = strText.replace("PrevMonth",premont)
            print(strText)
            p=Text_frame.paragraphs[0]
            p.clear()
            run = p.add_run()
            run.text= strText
            font= run.font
            font.color.theme_color = MSO_THEME_COLOR.DARK_2
            #font.color.rbg=RGBColor(87,24,24)



prs.save('test3.pptx')
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: the question is ? there is a way to give a text format like Shadow ext ext

Answer (score 2):

As of version 0.6.7, python-pptx does not yet have the API to control text shadows.

You can view and add comments (perhaps a +1) to the feature request on the GitHub issues list for the project here: https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/130